# Which version of Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, users, profile

We are looking into getting a server as we currently have only a workgroup and over 30 users and 25 workstations.

We want to setup a domain so we can setup group policies for everyone without manually altering all computers. We would also like to install Word, Excel and a few other applications onto the server and then limit access depending on the user's access level.

Each user would have their own login and then I would split the users into permission levels.

If this is making sense so far, is it all achievable with Microsoft Small Business Server 2008, or do we need something more advanced?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Are you looking to use it as a Terminal Server?

Comment: If Terminal Services allow us to deploy software to each workstation, then yes.

Comment: No, you would use Group Policy and/or WSUS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx) for deployment.

Comment: So would we need to use it as a Terminal Server for roaming profiles? Sorry - I know these are basic questions.

Comment: No, you can use roaming profiles without TS.

Comment: OK, thanks. In that case - No, we aren't looking to use it as a Terminal Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would do just fine with either SBS, or Standard edition.

Comment: I'd go with Standard unless you need a specific feature in SBS.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Exchange then just get 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: We're using Google Apps for our email so I think your spot on in your suggestion. 2008 R2 Standard it is! Thanks.